# In javascript, creating a class instance in a for loop

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following class for which I wish to create a series of instances:

```
function rashnik(size, name) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "pics/"+name+".jpg";
    img.height = size;
    img.width = size;
    img.id = name;
    d = 300-size;
    img.style.marginBottom = d/2;
    img.style.marginLeft = 50;
    var gal = document.getElementById("gallery");
    gal.appendChild(img);
};
```

Now, Iv'e created this function to create the instances:

```
function creater(names) {// the argument "names" would be a two-dimensional array 
    for (var a = 0; a < names.length; a++){
        var names[a][0] = new rashnik(names[a][1], names[a][0]); // right here is where I get the error
    }
}
```

And this is how I try to call it:

```
var friends = [["adi","300"],["tom","200"],["sleg","100"],["dorc","50"],["dork","25"]];
creater(friends);
```

The thing is, the `var names[a][0]` part throws me an error, which I totally understand; I want to create an object whose name is the same as the string stored in `names[a][0]`, but, well, it just doesn't work that way.
Does anyone have an idea as to what I could to to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up. I  think this is doing what you want:

- Create a new class instance in the loop, so it's an object
- Put *something* in that object.  I put the img in as an example.
- Use the name as the "key" of a returning object.  I access that in the alert in the code below by using `resultsView['adi']` but could have also done `resultsView.Adi`

http://jsfiddle.net/w7wKW/

```
function rashnik(size, name)
{
var img=document.createElement('img');
img.src = "pics/"+name+".jpg";
img.height = size;
img.width = size;
img.id = name;
d = 300-size;
img.style.marginBottom = d/2;
img.style.marginLeft = 50;
var gal = document.getElementById("gallery");
gal.appendChild(img);

    this.img = img;
    return this;
};


function creater(names)
{//the argument "names" would be a two-dimensional array
    var results = { };
for(var a=0; a<names.length; a++)
{
results[names[a][0]] = new rashnik(names[a][1], names[a][0]);
}

    return results;
}

var friends = [["adi","300"],["tom","200"],["sleg","100"],["dorc","50"],["dork","25"]];
var resultsValue = creater(friends);

alert(resultsValue['adi'].img.src);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
Could you explain why? Especially the `result = {}` part?

Comment: `result = { };` creates an empty object.  I could have done `result = { hello: 'world' }` after which I could have done `result.hello` or `result['hello']` to access the string `world`.

If this answers your question, please accept the answer, thanks!